# Javascript appending a line break at the end of every outputted array value

Tags: javascript

When I run the following code the br is appended to the end of the the dates list. I am trying to get the br to append after every date value in the array. I tried using a for loop but that doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
dates = ['2012-09-06 22:39:29', '2012-09-06 22:41:02', '2012-11-05 15:01:10', '2012-11-06 15:37:58', '2012-09-08 10:22:00'];

$('#hi').append(dates.sort() + '<br>');
```

For loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    $('#hi').append(dates.sort() + '<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your'e effectively concatenating the whole array with the BR tag.
consider the following exapmle:

```
  dates.sort();
    for(i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        $('#mydiv').append(dates[i] + '<br>');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
dates.sort();
$("#hi").append(dates.join("<br />") + "<br />");
```

I don't know what you think `dates.sort()` does, but you're using it weird.

Comment: Doesn't it sort the dates in order?